# How are Zeta function values calculated from within the Critical Strip?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, functional-equations, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

We note that for $Re(s) > 1$

$$ \zeta(s) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^s} $$

Furthermore

$$\zeta(s) = 2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin \left(\frac{\pi s}{2} \right) \Gamma(1-s) \zeta(1-s)$$

Allows us to define the zeta function for all values where

$$Re(s) < 0$$

By using the values where $$Re(s) > 1$$ But how do we define it over

$$ 0 \le Re(s) \le 1$$

Which is where most of the "action" regarding the function happens anyways...

Comment: have you checked in literature?

Comment: I explored wikipedia, didn't find anything that explicitly remedied the issue. Unless it is one of those integration relations example : $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{\infty}\left[ \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1} \ dx \right] $

Comment: But it was not explained if that or any other relation is defined for $0 \le Re(s) \le 1$

Comment: The most naive method would be to use a Taylor Series centered at a point not in the critical strip.  Since the only pole is at 1, you can easily select a base point to get convergence at any point in the critical strip you desire.  Not saying this is a good way, but it is a way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An extension of the area of convergence can be obtained by rearranging the original series. The series

> $$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{n}{(n+1)^s}-\frac{n-s}{n^s}\right)$$

converges for $\Re s > 0$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: Wiki doesn't explain the derivation of it, where is the best place to go for that?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: Try to consult one of the books on zeta function. Try to manipulate the expression $(1-s)\zeta(s)$ using the series $\zeta(s)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^s}$.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: Chapter 3 of *The Prime Number Theorem* by G.J.O. Jameson has a good explanation of extending the definition of the $\zeta$ function essentially as the accepted answer suggests.

Comment: @daniel: Thank you for giving a reference. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Good to have you back, Mhenni ! :-$)$

Comment: @Lucian: Thank you for your nice comment. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

This is an outline of the steps taken in the ref. in the comments to derive an expression for $\zeta(s)$ which converges for $\sigma>0$ and which can be modified slightly to allow approximation of values of $\zeta(s).$

Letting $f(s) = 1/x^s$ and $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^s}=\frac{1}{s-1}$ for $\text{Re}(s)>1$ and using (proof omitted)

$$\sum_1^{\infty}f(r)-\int_1^{\infty}f(t)dt = f(1)+\int_1^{\infty}(t-[t])f'(t)dt$$

we get

$$(*)\hspace{10mm}\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{(s-1)}+1-s\int_1^{\infty}\frac{x-[x]}{x^{s+1}}dx. $$

Since $x - [x] < 1$ the integral on the right converges for all $\sigma > 0.$

The above is of no use for computation so using Euler's summation formula for partial sums,

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}f(n) = \int_1^N f(x)dx+\int_1^N(x-[x])f'(x)dx,$$

applying this to $f(x)= 1/x^s$ in which $(s \neq 1)$ we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^s}=1 + \frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1}-s\int_1^N\frac{x-[x]}{x^{s+1}}dx $$

in which the term $1$ is just $f(1).$

Subtracting this from (*) we get

$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1} +r(s)$$

in which the term $r(s)$ can be shown to vanish as $N\to\infty.$

And so we have

$$\zeta(s) = \lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1} \right)$$

Now if I use this to calculate $\zeta(1+it)$ along the imaginary axis from $t = 0$ to $t = 36$ as Jameson does in his text, or other values, I get good approximations for even low values of N. For $s= 3/4+i $ and $N=1000$  I get $\zeta(3/4+i)\approx 0.33-.87i$ which agrees with $Mathematica's$ figure pretty closely.

The list of results omitted to do this is not long and they are all furnished in the noted reference.

Answer (score 5):

Although unmentioned by the others, once you have a functional equation, you can also use a so-called "approximate functional equation". In this case, it may seem circular, because knowing the functional equation implicitly involves understanding the values in the center of the strip.

But in fact, the approximate functional equation is an extremely efficient method of approximating values in the critical strip. A reference on wikipedia the [Riemann-Siegel formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Siegel_formula). A slightly looser explanation is that for $s = \sigma + it$, we have
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n^s} \ + \ \gamma(1-s) \ \sum_{n\leq y}\frac{1}{n^{1-s}} \ + \ O(x^{-\sigma}+ \ |t|^{\frac{1}{2}-\sigma}y^{\sigma - 1}),$$
where $\gamma(s)$ is a ratio of Gamma functions and you can choose $x,y$ to give the approximations of desired size. This works poorly on the edges of the critical strip, but very well in regions bounded away from the edges. It works especially well on the critical line, which is of special interest.

Answer (score 4):

There is a well-known relation between the [Riemann $\zeta$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and the [Dirichlet $\eta$ functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function): $$\zeta(s)~=~\frac{\eta(s)}{1-2^{1-s}}~,$$ where latter's series converges for all positive values of the argument. See [Leibniz's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) and [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

It's $\tt\underline{usually}$ evaluated with the alternating series
$\displaystyle{\quad\color{#66f}{\large%
\zeta\left(\,s\,\right)
={1 \over 1 - 2^{1 - s}}
\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\left(\,-1\,\right)^{k - 1} \over k^{s}}}}$.

---

For example,
$\displaystyle{\zeta\left(\,1 \over 2\,\right)
={1 \over 1 - \,\sqrt{\,2\,}\,}
\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\left(\,-1\,\right)^{k - 1} \over \,\sqrt{\,k\,}\,}
\approx {\tt -1.4603545088095868129}}$

Comment: Or through this extension: $$\displaystyle \zeta(s) = \frac{1}{2\,(s-1)} \left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left( {\frac {n}{(n+1)^{s}}} + \frac{2\,s-1}{n^s} - {\frac {n-1}{\left( n-1 \right) ^{s}}}\right) \right), \qquad 0<\Re(s)<1$$ we get an even simpler (I believe the simplest) series-expression for: $$\displaystyle \zeta\left(\frac12\right) = \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\sqrt{n-1} -{\frac {n}{\sqrt{n+1}}}\right)$$

Comment: @Agno These are very nice expressions. It's curious that textbooks seldom mention these ones. Thanks.

Comment: I prefer applying the Euler transform to get a globally convergent series that converges very rapidly.  See my answer @Agno

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I agree with you. Euler-T... is better whenever we want to perform a numerical evaluation. Indeed, Euler invented that to apply to the Basel-Problem because he had to calculate manually. Thanks for your remark.

Comment: :-) Not to mention how easy it is.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt $\Huge^{@}\left({\bullet\quad\bullet \atop {\mid \atop \smile}}\right){^{@}}$

Comment: :O That's so cute!  You'll find many similar faces (hehe) here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art/?tab=stars&page=2

Comment: @FelixMann - your nice sketch of SimplyBeutifulArt's face reminds me of a formula giving a picture of a face, which I developed as pupil in school initially in a boring mathlesson below my desk... See the result with additions later back home at http://go.helms-net.de/math/bilder/Oberstufe1.jpg

Answer (score 4):

We may start by defining the Dirichlet eta function:

$$\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$$

We then have

$$\zeta(s)-\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac2{(2n)^s}=2^{1-s}\zeta(s)$$

You may then see that

$$\zeta(s)=\frac1{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}$$

While it is true this converges for $s>0$, it is easily extended through an [Euler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation):

$$\zeta(s)=\frac1{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^s}$$

While we still have an infinite sum to deal with, this converges crazy fast, and you can easily graph approximately $\zeta(s)$ on a good graphing calculator for all $s\in\mathbb R$:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/my05uiirse

Comment: Your last representation is not just crazy fast, but it's "smooth" when you plot the partial sums for complex $s$ (no wiggles).

Comment: @Davehuff Well, it is one of the fastest converging series representations of the Riemann zeta function is what I meant

Comment: As addition and visual example for the power of Euler-summation that @SimplyBeautifulArt mentions might be my comment/answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490308/show-how-to-calculate-the-riemann-zeta-function-for-the-first-non-trivial-zero/490447#490447 This computation is not only restricted to the $\mathfrak R (s)=1/2$ - case, btw.

Answer (score 3):

This shouldn't be taken as a complete answer....

One thing you must know is that the functional equation you mention

$\zeta(s)=\frac{(2\pi)^{s}}{\pi}\sin(\frac{\pi s}{2})\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)$

should not be used to calculate zeroes. What I think is used, and is relatively accessible, is the following reformulation

$\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})\zeta(s)=\pi^{-\frac{1-s}{2}}\Gamma(\frac{1-s}{2})\zeta(1-s)=\Lambda(s)$

Notice that $\Lambda(\bar{s})=\bar{\Lambda}(s)$. If you let $s=\frac{1}{2}+\imath y$, then you have $\Lambda(s)$ to be a purely real function for purely real $y$. You can use the intermediate value theorem if you can approxiamte $\Lambda$, show that for some interval it takes a positive output and a negative output, and home in on your zero within that zero (since $\Lambda$ is a continuous function).

The following representation, previously mentioned here, is an exceptionally nice way to compute $\zeta$:

$\displaystyle \zeta(s)=\frac1{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^s}$

Additional Edit:

The exponential $\pi$ and $\Gamma$ factors are never zero! So if this $\Lambda$ thing is zero, the zero is coming from $\zeta$!