# Show that when applying these substitution rules the result is an alternating sum with binomial coefficients in the numerators.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, substitution, mathematica

The following is Mathematica code. I apologize but I don't know how to write it more clearly.
`B1 = ReplaceAll[A1, x1 -> 1/A2];` simply means to take `A1` and within `A1` replace all `x1` with one divided by `A2` which is written `1/A2` where `A2 = xc/x1 - xc/x2;` The semicolon means that the output is not displayed/printed. If the semicolon is missing the output is displayed/printed. `ReplaceAll` is the same as substitute.

```
A0 = 1/x0

A1 = xc/x0 - xc/x1
A2 = xc/x1 - xc/x2;
A3 = xc/x2 - xc/x3;
A4 = xc/x3 - xc/x4;
A5 = xc/x4 - xc/x5;

B1 = ReplaceAll[A1, x1 -> 1/A2];
B2 = ReplaceAll[B1, x0 -> 1/A1]

C1 = ReplaceAll[B2, x2 -> 1/A3];
C2 = ReplaceAll[C1, x1 -> 1/A2];
C3 = ReplaceAll[C2, x0 -> 1/A1]

D1 = ReplaceAll[C3, x3 -> 1/A4];
D2 = ReplaceAll[D1, x2 -> 1/A3];
D3 = ReplaceAll[D2, x1 -> 1/A2];
D4 = ReplaceAll[D3, x0 -> 1/A1]

E1 = ReplaceAll[D4, x4 -> 1/A5];
E2 = ReplaceAll[E1, x3 -> 1/A4];
E3 = ReplaceAll[E2, x2 -> 1/A3];
E4 = ReplaceAll[E3, x1 -> 1/A2];
E5 = ReplaceAll[E4, x0 -> 1/A1]

FullSimplify[A0]
FullSimplify[A1]
FullSimplify[B2]
FullSimplify[C3]
FullSimplify[D4]
FullSimplify[E5]
```

When I apply `FullSimplify` this is what I get:

`FullSimplify[A0]`
$$\frac{1}{x_0}$$
`FullSimplify[A1]`
$$x_c \left(\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac{1}{x_1}\right)$$
`FullSimplify[A2]`
$$x_c^2 \left(\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac{2}{x_1}+\frac{1}{x_2}\right)$$
`FullSimplify[A3]`
$$x_c^3 \left(\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac{3}{x_1}+\frac{3}{x_2}-\frac{1}{x_3}\right)$$
`FullSimplify[A4]`
$$x_c^4 \left(\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac{4}{x_1}+\frac{6}{x_2}-\frac{4}{x_3}+\frac{1}{x_4}\right)$$
`FullSimplify[A5]`
$$x_c^5 \left(\frac{1}{x_0}-\frac{5}{x_1}+\frac{10}{x_2}-\frac{10}{x_3}+\frac{5}{x_4}-\frac{1}{x_5}\right)$$

I need to show that as I continue the replacement pattern within the code the result from `FullSimplify`for the $n$-th row is:

$$x_{c}^{n-1} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k-1} \binom{n-1}{k-1}}{x_{k-1}}$$

Comment: Should I add the expressions for `A0`, `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `A4`, and `A5` before I applied `FullSimplify` to them?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, only the expressions for the inputs to `FullSimplify`
`A0` $=\frac{1}{\text{x0}}$

`A1` $=\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x0}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}$

`A2` $=\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x0}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}\right)$

`A3` $=\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x0}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}\right)\right)-\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}\right)\right)$

`A4` $=\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x0}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}\right)\right)-\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}\right)\right)\right)-\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}\right)\right)-\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x4}}\right)\right)\right)$

`A5` $=\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x0}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}\right)\right)-\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}\right)\right)\right)-\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}\right)\right)-\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x4}}\right)\right)\right)\right)-\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x1}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}\right)\right)-\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x4}}\right)\right)\right)-\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x2}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x4}}\right)\right)-\text{xc} \left(\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x3}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x4}}\right)-\text{xc} \left(\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x4}}-\frac{\text{xc}}{\text{x5}}\right)\right)\right)\right)$