# is $\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\eta(s)$ an analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$ for $\sigma > 0$

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

It seems from what I have read on the net, that the above representation of $\zeta(s)$ is a valid analytic continuation of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^s}$ for $\sigma > 0$ except for a simple pole at $s=1$.

Is this not true?

Thanks

Comment: Yes${{{{{}}}}}$.

Comment: $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ is defined only for $\Re(s)>1$ since it diverges otherwise. $f(s)\equiv(1-2^{1-s})^{-1}\eta(s)$ can be shown to converge for $\Re(s)>0$ and be identically equal to $\zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s)>1$. Therefore $f(s)$ is an analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$, except at the problem point $s=1$ since the coefficient of $\eta$ there makes no sense.

Comment: Then I could consider a function $\zeta(sk) = \frac{1}{1-2^{1-sk}}\eta(sk)$ and draw conclusions about its behavior and tie that to $\zeta(s)$ for $k=1$ right?

Comment: Absolutely, yes, so long as you choose your $s$ and $k$ correctly, i.e. $\Re(sk)>0$. E.g. you could even have $\Re(s)<0$ so long as $k<0$. In general you can define a piece-wise function for different domains.

Comment: It is true if you add the definition $$\eta(s)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i^s},$$ and you could have read it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437883/what-is-the-analytic-continuation-of-the-riemann-zeta-function).

Comment: Thank you, I just posted some key observations about $\zeta(sk)$ and someone said it was wrong. I hope I can undelete that post. Specifically, my observation was that the zeros of $\zeta(sk)$ are on $\Re(s) = 0.5/k$ and $\Re(s) = 1/k$ for $k \ne 1$.

Comment: Most interesting is for $k \approx 1$ there are zeros on two real lines and obviously when $k=1$ the zeros end up being on one real line which is $0.5/k$

Comment: The function I used was this: $\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}} \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i^{sk}}$. Note by mistake I forgot to use $sk$ in the denominator. This is the function that has zeros on two real lines.

Comment: All, is there any interest in seeing the pictures of the zeros for several values of $k$? If it is meaningful, I don't mind showing that in another thread. Thanks

Comment: @sku Are you kidding ? For $|\Im(s)| < 10^{13}/k$ the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(sk)$ are on $\Re(s) = \frac{1}{2k}$. If you want to study books on $\zeta(s)$, you need to read first some real analysis and Fourier analysis and complex analysis courses.

Comment: @reuns the function I used was this. $\frac{\eta(sk)}{1 - 2^{1-s}}$. Note I forgot to use $sk$ in denominator.

Comment: Given $\eta(sk) = (1-2^{1-sk}) \zeta(sk)$, can you find where are the zeros of $\eta(sk)$ ?

Comment: Just to remove confusion, the function I used was $\frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i^{sk}}$ and studied its zeros. It is probably a meaningless function but helps to understand what happens to this function in the limit as $k \to 1$. This function has zeros on the two lines $\Re(s) = 0.5/k$ and $\Re(s) = 1.0/k$ for $k \ne 1$

Comment: @sku And poles on $\Re(s) = 1$. You didn't answer to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65009/discussion-between-sku-and-reuns).

Comment: I discovered something that seems to make sense. The zeros of \frac{1}{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i^{sk}} at $1.0/k$ for $k \ne 1.0$ are the trivial zeros of $1 - 2^{1-s}$ which occur at $1 + \frac{2n\pi}{\ln 2}$. So nothing new discovered here. Thanks for everyone's help.