# How to find $\zeta(s)$ for $\text{Re}(s)\leq 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

I was trying to build animation to show How $\zeta(1/2+it)$ would look as $t$ changes. If the $\text{Re}(s)$ were greater than $1$, I could simply use the definition of the zeta function.
$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$$

But as the above sum doesn't converge for $\text{Re}(s)\leq 1$, I'm in trouble. I don't know if I can use analytic continuation for it. So I'm asking if there is some trivial way to find $\zeta(1/2+it)$  for  $\text{Re}(s)\leq 1$.

Comment: If I were you, I'd hurry an have a look at the only answer before it gets deleted. It answers your question perfecty.

Comment: @G.Fougeron I don't get what are you saying?

Comment: Look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437883/what-is-the-analytic-continuation-of-the-riemann-zeta-function

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Dirichlet Eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$$

as this is valid for $s\gt0$ (so includes all of the critical strip), and also:

$$\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$$

and so when $\eta(s)$ is a zero, so is $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: It should be $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(2)$.