# What is the expansion of $2^{1-s}$?

Tags: arithmetic

I'm looking at Eqn. 12 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02301.pdf)

I tried the power rule $a^m \div a^n = a^{m-n}$ to get $2^1 / 2^s$. But probably this is wrong.

Looking at the equation this should probably be $1/2^s$.

Can you help?

EDIT:

I see in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437883/what-is-the-analytic-continuation-of-the-riemann-zeta-function) that the same expression is written in reverse as $2^{s-1}$ so this may be literally 2 raised to the power of $(1-s)$.

Comment: Your original understanding was right, $2^{1 - s} = \frac{2}{2^s}$.